# How to rename/save image in gallery

Tags: ios, swift, photo-gallery, photolibrary

I created a custom folder to save the image in the gallery through my application(which is achieved code as below). Now I want to set a custom name for that saved image. How can I achieve this challenge? If anyone possible to help me to achieve this challenge.

```
func save(image: UIImage, strName : String) {

        self.checkAuthorizationWithHandler { (success) in
            if success, self.assetCollection != nil {
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                    let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
                    let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
                    albumChangeRequest!.addAssets(enumeration)

                }, completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for saving image in custom album try this 
 ---  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673344/8536028

Comment: I did that saving part, but  it saved name like this IMG_XXXXX. I want to override with my custom name.

Comment: We can't rename the image name in the gallery that we are saving. iOS will handle this.

Comment: @Prakash: I'm also thing like that, Is there any document from apple we can't do.