# UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum Save Video File to Specific Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was able to save image to specific folder in Photos using this answer. [How to save image to custom album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708846/how-to-save-image-to-custom-album/30673344). 
And it was successfull. but cannot find a way to save video to specific folder. Currently im using `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` and it does save to Photos only.

Comment: No, use the same way Photos.Framework and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482738/swift-save-video-from-nsurl-to-user-camera-roll

Comment: @Larme Thank you very much. just had to replace this `creationRequestForAssetFromVideo` it worked.